# Past real conditional sentences with present tense and future tense in the main clauses

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

Example 1:

Imagine I wrote an article in a foreign language I am not very good at, so I wrote down something like (1) to indicate that I feel sorry about the possible imperfections in the article:

> (1) If I made a mistake, I am sorry about it.

Does it make sense to use past real condition in an if-clause and present tense in a main clause like this?

---

Example 2:

Imagine I was drunk when I was talking to my friend. I felt a little bit guilty about it the next day, so I said something like (2) to her:

> (2) If I hurt your feeling yesterday, I will make it up to you.

Does it make sense to use past real condition in an if-clause and future tense in a main clause like this ?

---

In short, can I mix past real condition and other tenses(future or present, etc) in a sentence like examples above to indicate my future actions corresponding to past events?

Comment: English-speaking people usually talk about *(not) hurting someone's feeling**s***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you're talking about **real** situations, past tenses refer to past events, present ones to present events, and constructions used to express the future to future events.